# retreive intent extra key value that was set in another class at MainActivity class

Tags: android

I created an intent that is used for a notification in a class that extends FirebaseMessagingService.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("URL", link);
```

The user should click on the notification and go to the link. How to get this intent extra key and value from Mainactivity inside onResume() after the user clicks on the notification?

Comment: Why onResume? If you send the intent to MainActivity you will get it via onNewIntent event in mainActivity, from there you can extract the data from the intent

Comment: I have added to onNewIntent but still i get nothing! @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Log.i(TAG, extras.getString("URL")); }

Comment: how do you send your intent? are you using something of the sort:
                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(serviceIntent); ?

Comment: I just use a pending intent getactivity and pass the intent at the pending intent, then i pass the pending intent to the nofitication. Actually it worked like this protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Log.i(TAG, extras.getString("URL")); } i guess i had to use setIntent before using getintent? I am a bit confused...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do something in onResume as when you are sending an intent from 1 class to another, onNewIntent event is fired

From the class you wish to send the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("URL", link);
context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

in the class you want to receive the intent:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.hasExtra("URL")) {
        String str = intent.getStringExtra("URL", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its working when the app is open but is not working when the notification arrives and the app has already been closed. I tap on the notification and the app opens but the link url page does not load. It goes directly to main webpage. onNewIntent is not triggered. Any thoughts?

Comment: @stefanosn in your onCreate you can call getIntent(), this should give you the intent which used to open the app. From there, get the information needed and do the actions you need.